Tridion CoreSerivce Rest API takes long time to return responses
We are experiencing slowness on tridion coreservice rest api
When implementing items API, It takes nearly 2 seconds to get a response by using Postman
https://test.cms.com/api/v1.0/items/tcm_13-125861?useDynamicVersion=true
When doing stress test for these following APIs in order, it takes average 5 seconds to get response
https://test.cms.com/access-management/connect/token   → get token
https://test.cms.com/api/v1.0/items/tcm_13-125861/checkOut    → check out component
https://test.cms.com/api/v1.0/items/tcm_13-125861?useDynamicVersion=true   → get component
https://test.cms.com/api/v1.0/items/tcm_13-125861    → edit the component
please suggest if response time can be improved or if there is any setting on CM side which needs update?

These are definitely not normal response times, indeed.
Please use the TCM Profiler feature (Start-TcmProfiler PowerShell cmdlet) to obtain profiler reports which give insight in where the time is spent, exactly.
